# Reduce file size of UIImage going wrong

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

I'm getting some wierd results trying to reduce the filesize of a `UIImage`.

---

### Code

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
        NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5f);
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

The variable `img` is what gets sent to the database. However it's never compressed.

What makes the whole thing even weirder is that it worked for a little while. That time i first tried to "fix it", but gave up and undid the changes. That's when it worked, when it went back to like before.

Later I made another change on a completely different part of the app, and again, the compression stopped working.

Does anybody have a clue of what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code gets a `UIImage` instance from the image picker controller (line 1), then compresses it as a JPEG file (line 2) and then expands (uncompresses) it again (line 3).

You don't want to send the expanded image (`UIImage` instance called `img`) to the database. Instead, you'll want to send the compressed JPEG image (`NSData` instance called `data`) to the database.

BTW: Did this code ever work? Is it possible at all to store a `UIImage` instance?

Comment: I forgot to mention this isn't where I actually send it. I'm sending it through another function later which is turning it back to NSData... Even though I still really can't figure out why img gets original size, I'm gonna give you the answer for giving me the slap in the face I needed to realize what a stupid setup I've made. Am changing the size in the sending function instead now. This made it all work again. :)